# Custom class with overloaded operators causes C2678 when used as map key

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, compiler-errors, operators

i've got something strange here.

I have written a custom class HashedString:

```
class HashedString {
        protected:
            std::string str;
            long hash;

        public:
            HashedString(std::string str);
            ~HashedString();

            std::string GetString();
            long GetHash();

            bool operator== ( HashedString & o ) {
                return this->hash == o.GetHash();
            }
            bool operator<= ( HashedString & o ) {
                return this->hash <= o.GetHash();
            }
            bool operator>= ( HashedString & o ) {
                return this->hash >= o.GetHash();
            }
            bool operator< ( HashedString& o ) {
                return hash < o.GetHash();
            }
            bool operator> ( HashedString & o ) {
                return this->hash > o.GetHash();
            }
            bool operator!= ( HashedString & o ) {
                return this->hash != o.GetHash();
            }
            std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs) {
                return lhs << "{" << hash << ": " << str << "}";
            }
    };


std::map<HashedString, Resource> resources;
```

When using it in a map as a key like above i get the following error:

binary operator '<' : no operator defined which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const HashedString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I am not able to get it work, furthermore i don't understand why this code is rejected by the compiler.

Does anybody know the solution and the mistake i have done here?

Thanks, Xeno

Comment: You need to read up on const correctness.

Comment: Also most of those operators should be free functions

Comment: there is no single const  - a downvote (besides the compiler specific error 2678)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your operator `const`. It should also take a `const` reference:

```
bool operator< (const HashedString& o ) const { .... }
```

Alternatively, you can make it a non-menber operator:

```
bool operator<(const HashedString& lhs, const HashedString& rhs)
{
  lhs.GetHash() < rhs.GetHash();
}
```

This would be the preferred option, since it is symmetrical for both operands.

Note that it doesn't make sense for a comparison operator to mutate either of its operands. This applies to all of your comparison operators.

Finally, for this to work, you will have to make `GetHash()` `const` too:

```
long GetHash() const;
```

**Edit**: I didn't go into this before, but clearly this mechanism is fragile against hash collisions. Unless you have perfect hashing in your range of key values, you may be better off using an `std::unordered_map<std::string>`.

Comment: Doing this causes a C2662: 'HashedString::GetHash': this-Zeiger cannot be converted from 'const HashedString' to 'HashedString &'

Comment: GetHash() also has to be declared as a const member function, as in long GetHash() const

Comment: @Nevin Thanks, I was on it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help!
It's working now :)

I'm sorry if this question was too simple for some but learning this without good references is hard

Comment: OTOH, unless you have a perfect hash function, it isn't a good idea to use this as a key in a map, as collisions in the hash function will result in "equal" strings.

Comment: @Nevin it really depends on OP's use-case, so I didn't go into that. Obviously it is fragile against hash collisions, but I imagine they are doing this for a reason (as opposoed to just using an `unordered_map<string>`.